# Enabling Cross Account Access to publish AWS ClouchWatch logs(Multiple Accounts) to Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have two aws accounts prod and prod-support.  In prod-support account I created a cross account role and attached a policy to grant access to prod account as  below. I have already created the kinesis stream in prod-support account and was in active state.

Now I am trying to create a cloudwatch subscription in prod account to redirect logs from cloudwatch logs(prod) -> kinesis (prod-support) account.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.aws_region}"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/deployment_role"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_policy" {
    name   = "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_policy"
    role   = "${aws_iam_role.tf_CWL_to_kinesis_role.id}"  
    policy = <<EOF
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::22222222:role/CrossAccountRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "kinesis:PutRecords",
                "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
                "kinesis:GetRecords"
              ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:${var.aws_region}:22222222:stream/tf_CWL_to_kinesis_stream"
        }       
      ]     
}EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_role" {
    name = "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS":"111111111"           
          },
          "Effect": "Allow"   
        }
      ]   
}EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_subscrp_filter" {
  name            = "tf_CWL_to_kinesis_subscrp_filter", 
  role_arn        = "${aws_iam_role.tf_CWL_to_kinesis_role.arn}"  
  log_group_name  = "/aws/lambda/egad-diagnostics-result-sender-lambda"
  filter_pattern  = ""
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:kinesis:${var.aws_region}:2222222222:stream/tf_CWL_to_kinesis_stream"
  depends_on = ["aws_iam_role.tf_CWL_to_kinesis_role"]
}
```

Couple of things to notice here.

1. Above terraform script uses assume role to execute. which means using prod-support credentials above terraform script assumes prod deployment-role to create the resources in prod account.
2. while creating cloudwatch subscription it tries to post message to kinesis steam. But i was not sure which role it is using to to post messages.

Above script is trying to access kinesis stream in prod-support account, but it was not able access it.

Any thoughts

Comment: Above might be possible but its an anti pattern which is creating cross dependencies.  Thus I have decided to avoid and keep the environments. So that we can tear down and create any time as and when needed.